# Function(s) within droppable + sortable function repeating YouTube videos after ended

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, youtube-api, jquery-ui-sortable, droppable

Currently have some code for a droppable and sortable playlist. For any subsequent functions, i.e. onclick functions, it seems I have to nest the functions within the sortable code. While testing functions with alerts I noticed it would repeat the alert around the position of the droppable/sortable, i.e. if it was the 4th droppable and it had been sorted a couple of times, the alert would repeat 6 times. This wasn't causing an issue with previous functions but I've implementing a Listening History function, and now it saves each video multiple times. If I take the function out of the sortable code, it no longer runs at all.

Here is the droppable/sortable:

```
$("#Playlist").droppable({
  tolerance: 'touch',
drop:function(event, ui) {
  ui.draggable.appendTo($(this));


  $(this).sortable({
    tolerance: 'pointer',
receive: function (event, ui) { // add this handler
  transferred = true;
```

and before closing this function, I nest the following:

```
$('.playlistYT').on('click', function(){
    $('#subHistory').click();
```

(and close it up). The playlistYT class is given to videos within the playlist. Is there something I should be adding to the droppable or sortable code to prevent the repetion of the $('#subHistory').click() function?

EDIT: Had a Google around and found LiveQuery, is this relevant to this issue? https://github.com/brandonaaron/livequery

EDIT 2: Problem seems to occur because of YouTube API function I'm currently using:

```
var nextVideo = $(this).parent().next().find('.playlistYT');
  player.addEventListener('onStateChange', function stopCycle(event) {
      if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
          $(nextVideo).click();
      }
  });
```

The nextVideo click is supposed to get the function to repeat for the new video in the Playlist, but when I look at the user history it saves the song multiple times depending on where in the playlist it is.

Comment: Use [event delegation](http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) maybe?

Comment: Thanks for the link, couldn't quite figure it out, went with livequery in the end.

Comment: Spoke too soon, still repeating with livequery! Will look again at event delegation...

Comment: Had a play around, seems the problem isn't with dragging and sorting, as when I click individual videos in the playlist they don't repeat the alert test, it's when another video is clicked automatically after the video ends that the alert test repeats (and increases with frequency with each subsequent video).